# Changing color of specific tab of top menu

Tags: menus, css

I am messed up with a problem and still i am unable to find it's solution.  I am trying to change color of only 1 tab in whole navigation menu.

I mean if my navigation bar include 5 tabs and i want to highlight one tab with a specific background color. But i don't have any idea to do this. Can you suggest some solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress Nav Menus support Custom CSS Classes. They can be used to change the colour of your tab. Refer this link -> http://devilsworkshop.org/add-custom-class-individual-menu-items-wpnavmenu/